# Codeigniter page won't refresh (Browser-Cache is turned off)

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I'm currently developing my first project with **codeigniter**. Here's a strange problem, I've encountered: When making little changes to a view or class, i'll have to wait for a few minutes before refreshing, otherwise i'm served the old version of the file.

Browser-Caching is, of course, switched off - I've tried ctrl-F5ing/shift-Refreshing - no success. Different Browsers -> same result.

The content is obviously cached server-side for a few minutes. Does codeigniter do so by default? If so, how can I turn this behaviour off?

Comment: CodeIgniter does not cache by default. It's not CodeIgniter unless you specifically turned caching on.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 3 does not cache by default. This is how to enable web page caching: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

I would suggest you do a search of your codebase to make sure it wasn't inadvertently added at one point.

If that isn't the culprit you should check with your host. Some hosts offer caching options such as Cloudflare to speed up your web pages. This may be turned on by default.

You can also try examining the response headers. There is a free online tool where you can make a request to your page and it will show you the response headers: https://www.hurl.it/

Here are some example response headers from something using Amazon's CloudFront as a cache:

```
X-Amz-Cf-Id:qQ09JK3b2H-XiDD1nR9Ee22DppxU-7X1Nt74rzDyhczOCPA0YvZ0Mg==
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips!
I triple-checked: Codeigniter cacheing is not enabled. I've tried with plain HTML on a non-codeigniter subdomain -> same results.
I'll get in touch with my host, they're not using CloudFront, but something is obviously delaying all changes I make...